# Is there another way to check if a remote device is connected other than using ping?

Tags: c#, ios

I'm currently using a ping method to detect when a specified IP Address connects and disconnects from the network. The device is an iPhone and it has come to the light that when the device is in sleep mode for a period of time the ping request are timed out, and the device enters and leaves WiFi at certain points of time with this code:

```
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ip_address);
        if ((pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) && ownerIsInRoom == false)
        {
            ownerIsInRoom = true;
            //Code for when ping reply is a success
            return;
        }
        else if ((pingReply.Status != IPStatus.Success) && ownerIsInRoom == true)
        {
            ownerIsInRoom = false;
            //Code for when ping reply is a fail
            return;
        }
```

Is there another method of checking to see if this iPhone is connected to the network even when sleep mode is active, or am I stuck with random connections and disconnections making the information unreliable?

Comment: You are trying to establish a connection from the server to the iphone. Why not doing the opposite? Moreover, if the iphone is on another network it will not work (without routing).

Comment: Reachability? I know it works with computer hosts, imagine it will work with any constant IP address or name.